# VBA: Find red cells and copy header

Tags: vba, excel

Background: I have already used the 'conditional' formatting to highlight the 10 lowest values in each row in light red.

Now, I am trying to compose a code that searches each row for the red marked cells and copies their name from the header row to a new sheet.

What I am aiming for is the following: a code that searches each row for the cells in red and that copies the name (in header) to the same row in another sheet (=result sheet). This should result in a result sheet with 11 columns: first column being the dates and the following 10 columns in that row being the names of the lowest values for that date.

This is the code that I have so far but it does not work:

```
Sub CopyReds()

Dim i As Long, j As Long

Dim sPrice As Worksheet
Dim sResult As Worksheet

Set sPrice = Sheets("Prices")
Set sResult = Sheets("Result")

i = 2
For j = 2 To 217
    Do Until i = 1086
        If sPrice.Cells(j, i).Offset(j, 0).Interior.Color = 13551615 Then
            sPrice.Cells(j, i).Copy Destination:=sResult.Cells(2, 2).Offset(j, 1)
        End If
    Loop
Next j

End Sub
```

Update: screenshot worksheet

[image: Worksheet]

Update 2: Screenshot result sample

[image: Result Sample]

Comment: Why are you advancing Cells(j, I) each time in the loop and also offset(j, 0) ?

Comment: Because i thought by offsetting that I would go through the next row? (fairly new to vba)

Comment: You are, but you are already going through the rows with Cells(j, i), so now you are doing it twice

Comment: What do you suggest I edit? The offset part or the cells?

Comment: it's a little too long, so I wrote it down to be clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your algorithm should be redesigned: instead of testing the cells displayed color, check if the value is below a limit. This limit can be calculated with WorksheetFunction.Small, which returns the n-th smallest element.

```
Sub CopyReds()
    Dim sPrice As Worksheet: Set sPrice = Sheets("Prices")
    Dim sResult As Worksheet: Set sResult = Sheets("Result")
    Const colPriceName As Long = 2 ' The column in which cells can be colored red and contains the names to copy
    Const clrCopy As Long = 13551615 ' The color which indicates that the cell should be copied (red)
    Const colResult As Long = 2 ' The column where the results should be copied
    Const rowResultFirst As Long = 2 ' First row on sResult to use for output
    Const lngCount As Long = 10 ' Copy lngCount lowest elements (the actual number may be higher due to ties)
    Const colSort As Long = 2 ' The column in which cells contain the values from which the lowest lngCount should be selected

    Dim varLimit As Variant: varLimit = Application.WorksheetFunction.Small(sPrice.UsedRange.Cells(2, colSort).Resize(sPrice.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1, 1), 10)
    Dim rowResult As Long: rowResult = rowResultFirst
    Dim rowPrice As Long: For rowPrice = 2 To sPrice.UsedRange.Rows.Count - sPrice.UsedRange.Row + 1 ' Loop until last row
        If sPrice.Cells(rowPrice, colSort).Value <= varLimit Then
            sResult.Cells(rowResult, colResult).Value = sPrice.Cells(rowPrice, colPriceName).Value
            rowResult = rowResult + 1
        End If
    Next rowPrice
End Sub
```

Based on the screenshots, I revised the code:

```
Sub CopyReds()
    Dim sPrice As Worksheet: Set sPrice = Sheets("Prices")
    Dim sResult As Worksheet: Set sResult = Sheets("Result")
    Const rowResultFirst As Long = 2 ' First row on sResult to use for output
    Const rowPriceFirst As Long = 2 ' First row on sPrice to process
    Const lngCount As Long = 10 ' Copy lngCount lowest elements (the actual number may be higher due to ties)
    Const colDate As Long = 1 ' The column which contains the dates
    Const colValueStart As Long = 2 ' The column where values start

    Dim rowResult As Long: rowResult = rowResultFirst
    Dim rowPrice As Long: For rowPrice = rowPriceFirst To sPrice.UsedRange.Rows.Count - sPrice.UsedRange.Row + 1 ' Loop until last row
        Dim colResult As Long: colResult = 1
        sResult.Cells(rowResult, colResult).Value = sPrice.Cells(rowPrice, colDate).Value
        colResult = colResult + 1
        Dim varLimit As Variant: varLimit = Application.WorksheetFunction.Small(sPrice.Cells(rowPrice, colValueStart).Resize(1, sPrice.UsedRange.Columns.Count - colValueStart + 1), lngCount)
        Dim colPrice As Long: For colPrice = colValueStart To sPrice.UsedRange.Columns.Count - colValueStart + 1
            If sPrice.Cells(rowPrice, colPrice).Value <= varLimit Then
                sResult.Cells(rowResult, colResult).Value = sPrice.Cells(rowResultFirst - 1, colPrice).Value
                colResult = colResult + 1
            End If
        Next colPrice
        rowResult = rowResult + 1
    Next rowPrice
End Sub
```

Comment: At first, I got the error: 1004 stating it could not get the Small function. After deleting "worksheetfunction" and changing my non numerics such as #NUM! it started running. Now it returns some values but not nearly enough. The code does not run through all columns or rows in the Prices worksheet. So I do not get the 10 lowest values for each row. Any ideas on that? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: The result displayed in the result sheet are also numbers in stead of the names in row 1 of sPrice. So actually the code should run through every column in each row to find the 10 lowest values and display the names of the columns with the lowest values for each row. Thanks again!

Comment: Can you post an example picture of the input and output sheets?

Comment: I am currently unable to work on it. Will post picture once able

Comment: My apologies for the delay. Please see the update in my question for a screenshot from my input sheet. The output sheet is just a blank sheet.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at the picture, and it is very different from what I thought. Could you please also post a picture about the required output? I mean you could copy paste manually a small sample with a few rows.

Comment: I updated my original question again with a sample. So for each of the 217 rows it should display the names from the column in which the red cell is located.

Comment: And which column contains the Date (e.g. Jan 1999)?

Comment: The first one, so column A

Answer (score 2):

I think your code should look something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyReds()
    Dim sPrice As Worksheet: Set sPrice = Sheets("Prices")
    Dim sResult As Worksheet: Set sResult = Sheets("Result")
    Const colPriceName As Long = 2 ' The column in which cells can be colored red and contains the names to copy
    Const clrCopy As Long = 13551615 ' The color which indicates that the cell should be copied (red)
    Const colResult As Long = 2 ' The column where the results should be copied
    Const rowResultFirst As Long = 2 ' First row on sResult to use for output

    Dim rowResult As Long: rowResult = rowResultFirst
    Dim rowPrice As Long: For rowPrice = 2 To sPrice.UsedRange.Rows.Count - sPrice.UsedRange.Row + 1 ' Loop until last row
        If DisplayedColor(sPrice.Cells(rowPrice, colPriceName)) = clrCopy Then
            sResult.Cells(rowResult, colResult).Value = sPrice.Cells(rowPrice, colPriceName).Value
            rowResult = rowResult + 1
        End If
    Next rowPrice
End Sub
```

**Update: handling conditional formatting**

If you use conditional formatting then VBA does not read the actual color displayed but the color which would be shown without Conditional Formatting. So you need a vehicle to determine the displayed color. I wrote this code based on [this source](http://www.excelfox.com/forum/showthread.php/338-Get-Displayed-Cell-Color-(whether-from-Conditional-Formatting-or-not)) but refactored it significantly, e.g. now it did not work in international environment and its readability was poor:

```
Function DisplayedColor(rngCell As Range, Optional bCellInterior As Boolean = True, Optional bReturnColorIndex As Long = False) As Long
    Dim ewbTemp As Workbook: Set ewbTemp = Application.Workbooks.Add() ' Creates a new workbook, so that none of the cells of other workbooks is tampered with (not even temporarily) - this may be overkill, you may centralize this object or use existing cells
    DisplayedColor = -1 ' Assume Failure and indicate Error
    If 1 < rngCell.Count Then
        Debug.Print "Error in DisplayedColor: rngCell contains more than 1 cell"
        Exit Function
    End If
    Dim objTarget As Object: Set objTarget = rngCell
    Dim i As Long: For i = 1 To rngCell.FormatConditions.Count
        With rngCell.FormatConditions(i)
            Dim bFormatConditionActive As Boolean: bFormatConditionActive = False
            Dim varValue As Variant: varValue = rngCell.Value
            Dim strFormula1 As String: strFormula1 = FormulaFromFormulaLocal(.Formula1, ewbTemp.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1))
            Dim varEval1 As String: varEval1 = rngCell.Worksheet.Evaluate(strFormula1)
            If .Type = xlCellValue Then
                Select Case .Operator
                    Case xlEqual
                        bFormatConditionActive = varValue = varEval1
                    Case xlNotEqual
                        bFormatConditionActive = varValue <> varEval1
                    Case xlGreater
                        bFormatConditionActive = varValue > varEval1
                    Case xlGreaterEqual
                        bFormatConditionActive = varValue >= varEval1
                    Case xlLess
                        bFormatConditionActive = varValue < varEval1
                    Case xlLessEqual
                        bFormatConditionActive = varValue <= varEval1
                    Case xlBetween, xlNotBetween
                        Dim strFormula2 As String: strFormula2 = FormulaFromFormulaLocal(.Formula2, ewbTemp.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1))
                        Dim varEval2 As String: varEval2 = rngCell.Worksheet.Evaluate(strFormula2)
                        bFormatConditionActive = varEval1 <= varValue And varValue <= varEval2
                        If .Operator = xlNotBetween Then
                            bFormatConditionActive = Not bFormatConditionActive
                        End If
                    Case Else
                        Debug.Print "Error in DisplayedColor: unexpected Operator"
                        Exit Function
                End Select
            ElseIf .Type = xlExpression Then
                bFormatConditionActive = varEval1
            Else
                Debug.Print "Error in DisplayedColor: unexpected Type"
                Exit Function
            End If
            If bFormatConditionActive Then
                Set objTarget = rngCell.FormatConditions(i)
                Exit For
            End If
        End With
    Next i
    If bCellInterior Then
        If bReturnColorIndex Then
            DisplayedColor = objTarget.Interior.ColorIndex
        Else
            DisplayedColor = objTarget.Interior.Color
        End If
    Else
        If bReturnColorIndex Then
            DisplayedColor = objTarget.Font.ColorIndex
        Else
            DisplayedColor = objTarget.Font.Color
        End If
    End If
    ewbTemp.Close False
End Function

Function FormulaFromFormulaLocal(strFormulaLocal As String, rngDummy As Range) As String
    Dim strOldFormula As String: strOldFormula = rngDummy.Formula
    rngDummy.FormulaLocal = strFormulaLocal
    FormulaFromFormulaLocal = rngDummy.Formula
    rngDummy.Formula = strOldFormula
End Function
```

Please also note the change in the If statement of CopyReds (now it calls the above function).

Comment: When running this I get a quick loading sign but no actual changes/activity... nothing gets filled in the Result sheet

Comment: Are you sure that the color of the cells you want to copy is exactly 13551615? Did you extract the value from an actual cell (e.g. Debug.Print ActiveCell.Interior.Color)? If you place a Breakpoint at the line starting with sResult.Cells, does it ever get hit?

Comment: I'm pretty sure because I recorded the macro to colour the cells. Placing a breakpoint does not seem to have any effect. Still nothing happens

Comment: And if you place the breakpoint at the line starting with If sPrice.Cells, does it get hit?

Comment: When running this code I get an error: 438, object doesn't support this property or method. the line : `strFormula1 = FormulaFromFormulaLocal(.Formula1, ewbTemp.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1))` causes this error. When hovering it indicates strFormula1 = "". Any idea how i can call this function?

Comment: Try if you can run the following three statements before the line in question: (1) Dim str As String: str = .Formula1 (2) Dim adr As String: adr = ewbTemp.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1) (3) Dim en As String: en = FormulaFromFormulaLocal("", ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1)), and tell me which of the above works and which break.

Comment: When running the first line I got the same error as before. The other 2 worked or did not give any error. The same error popped up again on the same line as before. Although when hovering over the 2 other lines it says for instance: adr = ""

Comment: I experimented, and found that FormatConditions can also contain ColorScale objects (conditional formatting introduced in Office 2007). Retrieving the actual displayed color is extremely complex. So I advise to redesign your algorithm and test the cells value instead of its color. See my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify my comment, you need to "advance" either the `Cells(j, i)` or the `Offset(j, 0)`.

If you decided to use `For` loops, try to stick with it for both cases:, see code below:

```
For j = 2 To 217
    For i = 2 To 1086
        Debug.Print sPrice.Cells(j, i).Interior.Color ' <-- for Debug only
        If sPrice.Cells(j, i).Interior.Color = 13551615 Then
            sPrice.Cells(j, i).Copy Destination:=sResult.Cells(2, 2).Offset(j, 1)
        End If
    Next i
Next j
```

Comment: It does not seem to be copying anything. It runs (judging on the 'loading' icon), but it does not actually copy or change anything.

Comment: @AxRo add the `Debug` line I've added and see what values you are getting at the immediate window

Comment: It runs a little longer but I still do not get any values or any changes in the workbook itself